# How to decrease number of Tabs in TabLayout (Facing Error Every time)

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, tabs

I have a tab layout with 4 tabs :

```
 private final String[] TITLE = {"NEAR BY", "GLOBAL", "ROOM", "PRIVATE"};
```

I don't want the "GLOBAL" tab in the TabLayout, so i removed it from the title array, so now it looks like this:

```
  private final String[] TITLE = {"NEAR BY", "ROOM", "PRIVATE"};
```

But, every time I run the app again, I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Here is my activity code:

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        Log.i(TAG, "Create fragment position: " + position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new NearbyFriendsFragment();
            case 1:
                GlobalFragment globalFragment = new GlobalFragment();
                setListener(globalFragment);
                return globalFragment;
            case 2:
                return new RoomFragment();
            default:
                return new PrivateFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Get page title: " + position);
        return TITLE[position];
    }
}
  @Override
public void onTabUpdate(int position, int countBadge) {
    Log.i(TAG, "On Tab update: " + position + " , Count Badge: " + countBadge);
    arrayCountBadge[position] = countBadge;
    customTabView(position, countBadge);
}
```

I am a beginner in Android development.

Comment: Hey, return the length of the array in `getCount()` method. That is `3`

Comment: tried, but now the Layout of GLOBAL is showing in ROOM and layout of ROOM is showing in PRIVATE. How to Fix this ? @Vishnu

Answer (score 1):

your getCount function returns 4 while array's size is only 3 try:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: tried, but now the Layout of GLOBAL is showing in ROOM and layout of ROOM is showing in PRIVATE. How to Fix this ?

Comment: your switch (position) doesn't match the order or items declared in TITLE  array, fix that.

Comment: case 0:
                    return new NearbyFriendsFragment();

                case 1:
                    return new RoomFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new PrivateFragment();


                default:
                    return new PrivateFragment();, it crashes it with this Error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3"   @Don Ha

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int noOfItems;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager FM,int itemCount) {
        super(fm);
        this.noOfItems=itemCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        Log.i(TAG, "Create fragment position: " + position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new NearbyFriendsFragment();
            case 1:
                 return new RoomFragment();
            case 2:
                GlobalFragment globalFragment = new GlobalFragment();
                setListener(globalFragment);
                return globalFragment;
            default:
                return new PrivateFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noOfItems;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Get page title: " + position);
        return TITLE[position];
    }
}
  @Override
public void onTabUpdate(int position, int countBadge) {
    Log.i(TAG, "On Tab update: " + position + " , Count Badge: " + countBadge);
    arrayCountBadge[position] = countBadge;
    customTabView(position, countBadge);
}
```

This way the size(or number of items) will be automatically updated. Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...